# Confusion over textbook formulae for directional characteristics of sound sources

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics

I'm currently reading Olson's *Elements of Acoustical Engineering*, in which formulae are given for the directional characteristics of various arrays of sound sources, all of which are stated in terms of ratios $R_\alpha$ of pressure at a given angle $\alpha$ to pressure normal to the array.

For example, the ratio given for an array of point sources is:

$$R_\alpha=\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi d}{\lambda}\sin\alpha)}{n\sin(\frac{\pi d}{\lambda}\sin\alpha)}$$

where: $n$ is the number of sources, $d$ is the distance between the sources and $\lambda$ is the wavelength

I've [plotted this function in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t2i3k21yy2), substituting $343/x$ for $\lambda$ where $x$ is frequency and 343 m/s is the speed of sound in air at room temperature (since, personally, I'm more used to looking at sound pressure plotted with respect to frequency).

The resultant graph shows a periodic function with both positive and negative values.

However, if such an array were approximated by real sound sources and the sound pressure was then measured with a microphone at a given angle $\alpha$ and normalised to the sound pressure measured normal to the array, one would expect to see something approximating the absolute value of the same function, i.e. no negative values (see the second function in the Desmos link, above).

What I'm interested in understanding is: What does a negative pressure ratio mean, physically, in this context?

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it possible that this has to do something with the phase of the resulting signal? Have you checked that?

Comment: Thanks @ZaellixA, and yes, it's a good thought but, if it is related to the phase in some way, it's not clear to me how exactly...

Comment: Yes, this is true, it is not very clear. I will try to have a look as soon as possible and let you know of my findings. Additionally, if you could provide some more info on chapter/page where this could be found it would be quite helpful.

Comment: It’s the acoustic analogue of an interference pattern in optics. The negative pressure result form destructive interference of the travelling waves. The absolute sign does not have much importance as you typically have a parity symmetry. What makes more physical sense is the square of $R$ which is proportional to power and this would be roughly the noise intensity that you would hear.

Comment: Many thanks, @ZaellixA! The relevant chapter from Olson is 2.4 "Series of Point Sources". Any ideas will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @lpz :) I understand the interference pattern in terms of destructive interference, but I would have expected the pressure ratio of the resulting frequency response to range from a minimum of zero (completely destructive interference) to one (completely constructive interference). It's the negative values of the resulting ratio that I'm puzzling over... Also, could you explain what you mean by "parity symmetry" here? Thanks!

Comment: The interpretation of minimum of $0$ and maximum of $1$ is valid only for the power, ie the square of the field. Typically, you can model pressure by a linear pde (e.g. d’Alembert’s) so the substitution $p\to-p$ does not change the physics. This is because you are looking at very small perturbations about certain baseline. Thus the absolute sign of the pressure is not really relevant.

Comment: Thanks again @lpz. The reason the negative pressure ratio is relevant to me is that I'm calculating the pressure ratios of systems involving combinations of n-point arrays and other systems (e.g. ring-shaped arrays, single point sources, etc.). The calculations return meaningful results only when the outputs are allowed to include regions with a negative sign. That is, calculations involving multiple arrays of sources give false outputs when the absolute values are taken. It's in this sense that the sign is "relevant" to me, and also why I remain confused as to what it physically represents.